# How to declare a date variable in sqlplus to pass as bind variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sqlplus

I want to pass a date as bind variable in Sqlplus. I used the suggestion provided [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2939749100346967872) but it seems declared bind variable passed as varchar2?

```
variable my_date varchar2(30)
exec :my_date := '2013-10-01';
select sysdate ,:my_date from dual where sysdate > to_date(:my_date,'yyyy-mm-dd');

 select sql_text, v.sql_id, name, value_string, datatype_string
  from v$sql_bind_capture vbc
  join v$sql v
 using (hash_value)
 where v.sql_id in ('8c5xc95vxc7yr', '6vn08798ax8bw', '61g3km3x621wt');


    SQL_TEXT    SQL_ID  NAME    VALUE_STRING    DATATYPE_STRING
select sysdate ,:my_date from dual where sysdate > to_date(:my_date,:"SYS_B_0") 6vn08798ax8bw   :MY_DATE        VARCHAR2(32)
select sysdate ,:my_date from dual where sysdate > to_date(:my_date,:"SYS_B_0") 6vn08798ax8bw   :MY_DATE        VARCHAR2(32)
select sysdate ,:my_date from dual where sysdate > to_date(:my_date,:"SYS_B_0") 6vn08798ax8bw   :SYS_B_0    yyyy-mm-dd  VARCHAR2(32)
```

How to pass a date variable as bind parameter in Sqlplus?

**update**
I wrote pl/sql code block to pass date variable as bind variable. Does bind variable type affect execution plan?

Answer (score 4):

As [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve050.htm#SQPUG133), you cannot define a date variable in SQL*Plus.

The bind variable is indeed passed as Varchar2 in your code, which exactly what AskTom says will happen. However the explicit date conversion method converts it to a date in the SQL engine.